# How to distinguish plus/equals and equals keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I want to use the plus and minus keys to trigger the zoom in and out functions in my web app. The following code works, mostly:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { // requires jQuery
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode === 189) { // minus
        zoom_out();
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 187) { // plus
        zoom_in();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The key code 187 it returned when pressing the =/+ key as well as the keypad + key. This is fine, if odd, but 187 is also returned from the keypad = key, which I don't want to use for zooming. How can I distinguish the +/=, =, and + keys?

Comment: You could use "keypress" instead of "keydown", because then you get the fully-translated character instead of just the keycode.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`+` already does this in the browser

Comment: If you're using keydown or keyup (as compared to keypress) you should be getting _different_ codes for the =/+ key and the keypad + key, but the same code for =/+ regardless of whether you hold shift. I get different codes with my keyboard as tested here: http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx#instant-test (My keypad doesn't have an = key though, so our keyboards must be different.)

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey) property.

If `e.shiftKey` is `true` (you guessed it!) Shift is being held down and so `e.keyCode === 187 && e.shiftKey` means `+` was pressed.